# Generating a random matrix with prescribed conditions

Tags: random, random-matrices

I need to uniformly generate a random matrix $X$ with positive integer entries satisfying a number of prescribed conditions:

- The matrix dimensions are prescribed, say $m\times n$
- For each row, the sum of the entries of that row is prescribed, ie $\sum_{j=1}^{n} X(i,j) = f(i)$
- For each column, the sum of the entries of that column is prescribed, ie $\sum_{i=1}^{m} X(i,j) = g(j)$
- Each entry $X(i,j)$ takes values in a prescribed positive integer interval, say $[a, b]$

It's clear for instance that a solution requires $\sum_{i=1}^{m}f(i) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}g(j)$, for both equal $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X(i,j)$. It's also important the prescribed positive integer interval is compatible with the prescribed functions $f$ and $g$, although there is room here.

How do I go about doing this concretely? If a numerical example is needed, take the prescriptions:

- $m = 8$
- $n = 18$
- $f(1)=f(2)=\dots =f(7) = 34$ and $f(8) = 32$
- $g(j)=15$ for all $j$
- The positive integer interval is $[1,4]$

Notice $(7 \cdot 34)+32=15 \cdot 18 = 270$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many of these you want to generate, a fairly simple approach is to use [Markov Chain Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) sampling; this can be used in practice to uniformly sample many combinatorial structures such as Latin squares; see, for example, [Jacobson and Matthews (1996)](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/230166173_Generating_uniformly_distributed_random_latin_squares).

Here's a solution which works in the more general situation that, for each cell in the matrix, you have a lower bound $l_{ij}$ and an upper bound $u_{ij}$ with $l_{ij}<u_{ij}$.  You need two very simple pieces of code.  One generates a valid matrix, not necessarily uniformly; this is easy just by starting off each matrix entry at $a$, and repeatedly picking a random incrementable entry and incrementing it.  The second piece of code just needs to randomly "tweak" the matrix; the only requirement is that the set of all matrices is connected via the tweaks.  In your case, the natural tweak is to pick two rows and columns, and add the $2\times2$ matrix $$T=\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}$$ provided the bounds are respected; we will show below that this is sufficient to connect all legal matrices.

To generate a matrix uniformly at random: generate a non-uniformly chosen matrix, and tweak it a large number of times.  The Markov chain Monte Carlo theory tells you how many times you need to tweak before the result is effectively uniformly random.  See the references; that time should be a low degree polynomial in the diameter of the space.  In practice it depends on how worried you are about uniformity; you can just run it for a reasonable amount of time and call it done.  Here's the first one I generated for your example parameters:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccc}
 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 3 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 1 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

> **Theorem:** The $2\times2$ tweaks connect the space of matrices.

Let $A$ and $B$ be distinct legal matrices; we will show that you can easily find a tweak of either $A$ or $B$ so as to reduce the $l_1$-norm $||A-B||_1=\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}-b_{ij}|$ by at least $2$.  This implies that you can get from $A$ to $B$ in at most $||A-B||_1/2$ tweaks.

Look at the sign pattern of $A-B$. There must be a $+$ somewhere, and there must be a $-$ elsewhere in the same row and a $-$ in the same column. Thus, there exist two rows and two columns such that the difference pattern is $\pmatrix{+&-\\-&*}$.  There are now two cases in which we can tweak this $2\times 2$ submatrix.  If $a_*>l_*$ (if $a_*>b_*$ we’re in this case), then we can subtract $T$ from $A$, reducing $||A-B||_1$ by either $2$ or $4$.  Similarly, if $b_*<u_*$, we can add $T$ to $B$, which also decreases the distance by either $2$ or $4$.  If neither of these is an option, then we must have $l_*=a_*=b_*=u_*$, but this contradicts the requirement that $l_*<u_*$.$\hspace{1em}\square$

Comment: Interesting. If M is your tweak matrix, of course -M is also a valid tweak matrix and if we can use any of those two tweaks then I believe the set of matrices **is** connected by tweaks. Connectivity can be derived from joining a random matrix to a simple base matrix by the tweaks. I haven't tried a proof but it looks reasonable: deforming the random matrix into the base matrix row by row, and in each row, say, from left to right.

Running time looks troublesome to calculate but that's more of a bonus. I'm more interested in the process itself. Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, a tweak requires an ordered choice of two rows and an ordered choice of two columns, neither pair of which is required to be consecutive. (If you reverse the order of either the rows or the columns, $M$ "looks like" $-M$.)

Comment: Oh, right. This makes coding for it simpler/more efficient.

Comment: Upon reflection (no pun intended) I think the Markov chain I defined is not reversible; you want that to ensure the stable distribution is uniform.  You might have to do it this way: if your current matrix is *legal* (each element is between $a$ and $b$) apply a completely arbitrary tweak (which might introduce up to $4$ illegal entries.)  If your current matrix is *illegal*, require that the tweak fix at least two illegal entries in a line if those exist, otherwise that it fix at least one.

Comment: I believe it is not reversible, yes: the more 1's and 4's a matrix has, the fewer matrices joined to it by a tweak there are. It is my understanding reversibility with uniform steady-state distribution would require these numbers to be the same for all matrices, is that correct? Allowing illegal matrices to be produced solves this problem for legal matrices, but what about illegal ones? I have looked into Jacboson and Matthews's article but admittedly I'm not super well-versed in these matters.

Comment: It's OK as it stands, provided the space is connected.  If you can get from matrix $A$ to matrix $B$ by a tweak, then the transition probability $p_{AB}$ is $1/d$ where $d=mn(m-1)(n-1)$ is the number of potential tweaks.  Since $p_{AB}=p_{BA}$, the uniform distribution is stationary under this Markov chain; since it's ergodic, the stationary distribution is uniform.  The only reason you'd need to deal with illegal matrices is if it turned out the space weren't connected.

Comment: For a given legal matrix $A$, the number of potential 'legal' tweaks (that is, tweaks that take it to another legal matrix) depends on how many $1$'s and $4$'s $A$ has. $d$ isn't always $mn(m-1)(n-1)$. I do believe the space is connected by tweaks, however.

Comment: Be careful! $d$ is the number of *potential* tweaks, not the number of *legal* tweaks; it's the same for all matrices.  In order to get a chain whose stable distribution is uniform, you need to pick a *potential* tweak at random; if it's not legal you just stay put at that step.  So even if $A$ and $B$ have different numbers of legal tweaks, and different numbers of "neighbors", you still have $p_{AB}=p_{BA}.$  This doesn't happen if you simply select randomly from the *legal* tweaks. I did get this right in the original post.

Comment: By 'if it's not legal you just stay put at that step', do you mean 'if the potential tweak generated is not legal, I simply ignore it and generate another potential tweak again (from all possible potential tweaks)'? I don't think this solves the problem because if this is the case, the probability of going from a legal matrix $A$ to a legal matrix $B$ is still $1/d$ where $d$ is the number of potential _legal_ tweaks for $A$, and this changes between legal matrices.

I am sorry for being bothersome and I appreciate you taking your time with me.

Comment: The assumption is that you are going to take samples repeatedly from the Markov chain to generate new matrices.  In practice you'll pick an appropriate fixed number $T$; step the chain $T$ times, sample, and repeat. So the fact that you're "staying put" at a matrix $A$ effectively increases the probability that $A$ is chosen.  This is important: say a matrix $A$ is off in a hard-to-get-to back alley of the space. "Hard to get to" probably implies "not many neighbors" so you'll "stay put" there for a while, making up for the fact that $A$ is remote and you probably won't find it very often.

Comment: Interesting. I see what you mean, and this should slightly change the code I had set up for it. Originally I had 'ignored' illegal tweaks and generated another one until I got a legal tweak, discounting these illegal generations in relation to total number of steps taken. This meant the fixed number $T$ actually could increase slightly based on how many illegal generations I ran into during the procedure, and also meant I didn't get to stay put at any one matrix at all. Thank you!

Comment: The tweaks do connect the space; I edited the answer to include the proof.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $l_* = a_*$ and $b_* = u_*$? I see no reason why this should imply $a_* = b_*$, and in fact it's not too hard to provide a counter-example; see [this](http://i.gyazo.com/a22b18de32e1e627f489fdd104ffc502.png) for instance, where A is the topmost matrix and B is the bottommost. I still believe it is connected, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24119/discussion-between-tad-and-fimpellizieri).